# PHPSecurityScanner & SpikePHPSecAudit - How do I?

Tags: php, security

How do I run PHP Security Scanner and SpikePHPSecAudit?

I've already extracted them at the root of my website and thought it could be run like phpSecInfo where you just navigate to

```
www.mySite.com/phpsecinfo/index.php
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

ps I am using Windows XP and XAMPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spike PHP SecAudit  does static analysis of the files,  its also very old. [Pixy](http://pixybox.seclab.tuwien.ac.at/pixy/index.php) and [RATS](http://www.fortify.com/security-resources/rats.jsp) are also static analysis tools for php, but I think Rats is the only one the three that is still maintained.   These tools will produce a lot of false positives and it takes skill to tell the difference between a real problem and meaningless output.

In terms of scanners you are best off with [Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/),  which will produce very few false positives.  Wapiti also very easy to use `python wapiti.py http://localhost/vulnerable_app/`.   I recommend downloading "Hackme Blog" from [The Whitebox](http://code.google.com/p/thewhitebox/).   Many apps aren't immediately vulnerable,  sometimes you have to use the app a bit before the vulnerability can be reached.  Try scanning the blog after a fresh install,  then login as the admin and create a blog entry and then scan it again.

If all goes well I'll see an exploit of yours on BugTraq,  Give a shout out to "The Rook" ;).

Comment: @01010011 your welcome.  SO is mostly for white heads,  if you need help with exploit dev try and get my attention,  I check my comments.